# CSS3 Perspective: Visualising the view pyramid

Tags: css, css-transforms, perspective, perspectivecamera

From reading this article:
http://www.eleqtriq.com/2010/05/understanding-css-3d-transforms/
I can understand how the `perspective` property can be visualised as creating a pyramid in 3d space.

[image]

What I'm not too clear about is the phrase, "the sides of the cube are distorted and projected onto the pyramid", and then "The higher the perspective, the steeper the pyramid, so the transformed objects size will be nearer to it's untransformed size."

The diagram appears to show what would happen if a light had been shone from the right hand side, and the square on the right side of the cube is casting a distorted shadow on the pyramid. But since this is on the edge of the pyramid - on the very edge of our field of view, how is this actually useful?

And I understand that a higher perspective creates a steeper pyramid - but why would this create objects that were *less* distorted?

Can anybody clarify these points? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the diagram is specially clarifying.

What the pyramid does is project your elements (the cube) to the "floor" of the pyramid - the projection plane, where z=0.

If you forget absolutely about perspective, then your drawing system is to project the elements to the projection plane thru the perpendicular line. That is, seting the z of the coordinate to 0. (x y z) >>> (x y 0).

When you have a stepper pyramid, the angles of the pyramid are closer to the perpendicular, and that's the reason of the *less* distortion